# How to print wide character using JNI

Tags: c, java-native-interface, widechar

On a **32-bit Ubuntu** machine, from **JDK 1.7.0**, I'm unable to print wide characters.

Here is my code:

#### JNIFoo.java

```
public class JNIFoo {    
    public native void nativeFoo();    

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("foo");
    }        

    public void print () {
        nativeFoo();
        System.out.println("The end");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new JNIFoo()).print();
        return;
    }
}
```

#### foo.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "JNIFoo.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIFoo_nativeFoo (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
  fwprintf(stdout, L"using fWprintf\n");
  fflush(stdout);
}
```

Then I'm executing the following commands:

```
javac JNIFoo.java
javah -jni JNIFoo
gcc -shared -fpic -o libfoo.so -I/path/to/jdk/include -I/path/to/jdk/include/linux foo.c
```

Here is the result depending of the JDK used to execute the program:

**jdk1.6.0_45**/bin/java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/jni_test JNIFoo

> using fWprintf
>
> The end

**jdk1.7.0**/bin/java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/jni_test JNIFoo

> The end

**jdk1.8.0_25**/bin/java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/jni_test JNIFoo

> The end

As you can see, with JDK 1.7 and JDK 1.8, the fwprintf has no effect!

So my question is what am I missing to be able to use wide chars using JDK 1.7 (and 1.8) ?

Note: if I call **fprintf** instead of **fwprintf**, then there is no problem, everything is print out correctly.

#### Edit

Based on the comment of James, I created a main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include "JNIFoo.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  fwprintf(stdout, L"In the main\n");  
  Java_JNIFoo_nativeFoo(NULL, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Then I compile it like that:

```
gcc -Wall -L/path/to/jni_test -I/path/to/jdk1.8.0_25/include -I/pat/to/jdk1.8.0_25/include/linux main.c -o main -lfoo
```

And set LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/jni_test
```

And it is working correctly:

```
In the main
using fWprintf
```

So the problem may not come from C.

Note: it's working correctly on a 64-bit machine.
I have similar problem using linux Mint 32-bit.

Comment: Maybe printing/determining the `int` return value from `fwprintf()` may shed some light?

Comment: Whh do you need `fwprintf()`? What's wrong with `fprintf(stdout, ”%Ls", L"using fWprintf\n");`?

Comment: @chux fwprintf() returns -1 (jdk 1.7.0 and 1.8.0). errno has no error. ferror is ok.

Comment: @AlexCohn that's how our program is working. The code in my question is just some code that I simplified.

Comment: @dalf So at least `fwprintf()` is consistent with return -1 and not printing for "fwprintf function returns the number of wide characters transmitted, or a negative value if an output or encoding error occurred".  Hmmmmm.

Comment: How do you know that your problem has anything to do with Java?  Have you tried writing a C program that calls your Java_JNIFoo_nativeFoo() method?.

Comment: @jameslarge good question. I edited my question. I created a main that calls Java_JNIFoo_nativeFoo() and it is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You must not mix printing of narrow and wide characters to the same stream.  C99 introduced the concept of *stream orientation* whereby an I/O stream can be *wide-oriented* or *byte-oriented* (prior to C99, wide characters did not exist in the C language standard).  From C99 §7.19.2/4–5:

> 4) Each stream has an *orientation*. After a stream is associated with an external file, but before any operations are performed on it, the stream is without orientation. Once a wide character input/output function has been applied to a stream without orientation, the stream becomes a *wide-oriented stream*. Similarly, once a byte input/output function has been applied to a stream without orientation, the stream becomes a *byte-oriented stream*. Only a call to the `freopen` function or the `fwide` function can otherwise alter the orientation of a stream. (A successful call to `freopen` removes any orientation.)<sup>233)</sup>
>
> 5) Byte input/output functions shall not be applied to a wide-oriented stream and wide character input/output functions shall not be applied to a byte-oriented stream. [...]
>
> <sup>233)</sup> The three predefined streams `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are unoriented at program startup.

The C99 standard leaves mixing narrow- and wide-character functions as Undefined Behavior.  In practice, the GNU C library says "There are no diagnostics issued. The application behavior will simply be strange or the application will simply crash. The `fwide` function can help avoiding this. " ([source](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-I18N.html))

Since the JRE is in charge of program startup, it's in charge of the `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` streams and therefore also their orientations.  [Your JNI code is a guest in its house, don't go changing its carpets.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/04/30/10004931.aspx)  In practice, this means you have to deal with whatever stream orientation you're given, which you can detect with the [`fwide(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwide) function.  If you want to print wide characters to a byte-oriented stream, too bad.  You'll need to work around that by convincing the JRE to use wide-oriented streams, or convert your wide characters to UTF-8, or something else.

For example, this code should work in all cases:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIFoo_nativeFoo (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
  if (fwide(stdout, 0) >= 0) {
    // The stream is wide-oriented or unoriented, so it's safe to print wide
    // characters
    fwprintf(stdout, L"using fWprintf\n");
  } else {
    // The stream is narrow oriented.  Convert to UTF-8 (and hopefully the
    // terminal (or wherever stdout is going) can handle that)
    char *utf8_string = convert_to_utf8(L"my wide string");
    printf("%s", utf8_string);
  }
  fflush(stdout);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand your answer and it makes sense. But despite fwide(stdout,0) returns 0 which means the stream has no orientation yet, fwprintf doesn't work using JDK 1.8. (but it's working using JDK 1.6).

Answer (score 0):

@dalf,
The problem is outside JDK. It's in 32 bit version of GLIBC.
Please try to reproduce it on your machine:

I) create 3 files:

```
---foo.c: 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <wchar.h> 

void foo() { 
  fwprintf(stdout, L"using fWprintf\n"); 
  fflush(stdout); 
} 

----main.c: 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <dlfcn.h> 

int main(int argc, char **argv)  { 
    void *handle; 
    void (*foo)(); 
    char *error; 

   handle = dlopen("libfoo.so", RTLD_LAZY); 
   if (!handle) { 
     fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror()); 
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
   } 

   dlerror(); 

   *(void **) (&foo) = dlsym(handle, "foo"); 

   if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  { 
     fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error); 
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
   } 

   (*foo)(); 
   dlclose(handle); 
   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); 
} 

----mapfile: 
SomethingPrivate { 
    local: 
        *; 
};
```

II) run commands:

```
$ gcc -m32 -shared -fpic -o libfoo.so foo.c 
$ gcc -m32 -Xlinker -version-script=mapfile -o main main.c -ldl 
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="." 
$ ./main
```

and see what does it print to output